# can't trigger a test of some appllication via Jenkins job

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, devops

I am a beginner at the field of Devops.

I have created a simple web application (jsp), using 3 Jenkins jobs to store the code in GIT, to deploy the this app into Tomcat, and also to site-monitor this app (respectively).

Now, I have been trying - with no success -to automate a simple test with 2 verifications of my app functionality, using Selenium IDE and triggering it via Jenkins job (the fourth one in my project).

In order to perform it , I created the following job on Jenkins, with the needed plugin added (which is SeleniumHQ htmlsuite Run).

Here is the job:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pm6a.png

The job running has failed,giving the following error which I cant handle.

When I run it, I get the following error :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXGmI.png

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: @DebanjanB read carefully: Now, I have been trying - with no success -to automate a simple test with 2 verifications of my app functionality, using Selenium IDE and triggering it via Jenkins job (the fourth one in my project).

Answer (score 0):

Just tick `Delete workspace before build starts` box under **Build Environment** stanza

[image]

If you don't have the option in your Jenkins job configuration - make sure that [`Workspace Cleanup Plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) is installed

If you're [running your Selenium tests via Jenkins Pipeline](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/jenkins-pipeline-selenium/) - all you need to do is to put `cleanWS()` directive somewhere in your pipeline code or [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)

[image]

Comment: @ Dmitri T  it doesn't work...still gives me the same error